# Custom Mail Logo Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, email

I am sending a special welcome email to a registered customer.

eMail is sending fine. The problem is, it takes the logo and footer specified in luma theme Magento_Email.

In my own theme, i created Magento_Email with custom logo and custom footer. but it still takes the luma theme's parts.

Actually i thought my theme has a problem. But, every other customizing work in my theme works fine. So, the theme han't the problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: hi @Mr.Metz i have used custom email template and configured theme setting from content->Design->Configuration But still logo getting from luma theme can u advise ?

Comment: @Mr.Metz have you got a solution for the same? if got solution please write here.

Answer (score 1):

put your Logo @

```
root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor_Name}/{Theme}/Magento_Email/web
```

remove your `pub/static/frontend/` and run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and try

Comment: i did this but it didn't change. Still showing Luma

Comment: @Mr.Metz, have you removed `pub/static/frontend/`? and ran the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command?

Comment: yeah 4 sure @magento two

Answer (score 0):

Logo's for emails can be set in

`Content->Design->Configuration` and click on `Edit` for your theme then upload logo in transactional email.

Comment: yeah logo for standard mails could be set there but seems not to work for special mails

Comment: magento 2 have path issue with email logo,  so directly upload in pub/media/email/

Comment: as i said... the normal email logos are correctly. I noticed the path issue but this ist not my problem